# Python OpenCv build is not detecting visual studio 2019 in command line

Tags: c++, python-3.x, visual-studio, opencv, python

When i try to build the opencv package in python using command line

```
PS C:\Program Files\Open_CV\opencv-python> python setup.py build
```

It throws an error:
Version:  4.3.0+3073e9e
setup.py:85: DeprecationWarning: SO is deprecated, use EXT_SUFFIX
  ['python/cv2[^/]*%(ext)s' % {'ext': re.escape(sysconfig.get_config_var('SO'))}],
 Trying "Visual Studio 14 Win64" generator
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.18363.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (PROJECT):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

MSBuild.exe
to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

The system cannot find the file specified
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Program Files/Open_CV/opencv-python/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".[image]

Trying "Visual Studio 14 Win64" generator - failure
scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.

Building windows wheels for Python 3.8 requires Microsoft Visual Studio 2017.
Get it with "Visual Studio 2017":

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

Answer (score 0):

They don't automatically detect VS2019 yet.  You have to specify the generator.

```
python setup.py build -G "Visual Studio 16 2019"
```